# How do I get my background image to fit exactly within its responsive container - i.e. NOT keeping its aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, django, background-image

All questions I come across talk about keeping an image's aspect ratio. I **don't** want the image to keep its aspect ratio. I want the image's width to exactly match the container's width, and the image's height to exactly match the container's height. The container is responsive.

None of the settings I have tried solve this problem. Assuming my image is originally square and the responsive container is a horizontal rectangle:

`background-size: cover;` This fills the container horizontally but keeps the aspect ratio, so it doesn't squash the image to fit completely within the container.

`background-size: contain;` This fills the container vertically but repeats the image to fill it horizontally. It does not stretch the image horizontally to fill the container.

Auto, inherit, unset, etc. are all just variations of keeping the aspect ratio.

How can I make it so that my image dimensions match exactly the responsive container dimensions?

My website project is only using DJango, CSS, HTML.

Comment: You can set height 100% and width 100% to the image but if the container is an horizontal rectangle and image is a square, the image stretches.....

Comment: How do I set the width and height of the background image independently? I have my `background-image: url('{% static 'image.png' %}');` and if I set width or height, it's applying it to the container and not the background image

Comment: Look up the CSS background-size property (in this case set them both to 100%),

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I was trying background-size-width before. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks to Sfili_81 and A Haworth in the comments)

The answer is to set the background size using the following:

`background-size: 100% 100%`